# Why doesn't Option Explicit catch ReDim <undeclared>?

Tags: vba, excel, explicit

Does anyone know why this doesn't throw a `Variable not defined` error when I compile it?

```
'Class1.cls'
Option Explicit

Public Sub foo()
    ReDim fubar(1 To 2, 1 To 1)
End Sub
```

Am I misunderstanding how `Option Explicit` is supposed to work?  Or is there something wrong with this test?  Or is this just a bug in VBA?

(I am testing this on Excel 2007)

Comment: ReDim is a standard (implicit) procedure, so you are just passing the arguments to a proc; Option Explicit does not trigger in this case.

Comment: @AlexBell No, without the ReDim, passing an undeclared variable to a proc still generates the "undeclared variable error".  I think that Adrien Lacroix has it right.

Comment: Yeah, I agree! Anyway, the final conclusion: it's not a bug, but a documented behavior.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/y9341s4f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

"*When Option Explicit appears in a file, you must explicitly declare all variables using the Dim or ReDim statements.*"

So ReDim works in **Option Explicit**.

Comment: Yeah, it's works but it's still a bad way to program. However, I don't know if it's has an impact on performance.